# Encoded Cookies Error

Tags: asp.net, cookies, encoding

My application is separated in 3 different layers. WEB, BLL and DAL.
I set a cookie from web layer and then I requested it from another page to display it to the user.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["FlashMessenger"]["Type"] = "error";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["FlashMessenger"]["Message"] = "Aucun vol trouvé pour la date donnée. S'il vous plaît affiner votre recherche.";
```

when I am doing the same from BLL and trying to display it, the returned message is broken.

```
var flashMessengerC = Request.Cookies["FlashMessenger"];
var message = flashMessengerC["Message"];
var type = flashMessengerC["Type"];
MsgLBL.Text = message;
```

This is what I received "Aucun vol trouvÃ© pour la date donnÃ©e. S'il vous plaÃ®t affiner votre recherche."

I tried to Html encoded and afterwards decoded but it does the same. 
I had a look on browsers cookies and there was in correct format.

What could cause this?

I will appreciate any comment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't be 100% sure, but sounds like your BLL is running a different thread culture to your UI.  Having your BLL requesting cookies isn't a great design anyway - better to have the information they actually need passed into them, rather than tying it to a particular implementation, e.g.:

```
class FlashMessengerInfo
{
     public string Message { get; set; }
     public string Type { get; set; }
}

class MyBLL
{
   public MyBLL(FlashMessengerInfo messageInfo)
   {
   }
}
```

from the web ui, you'd populate this object and pass it on through to your BLL, leaving it uncoupled from the HttpRequest object.

Comment: I did't set any thread culture. I can't understand what cause this. Anyway, I've set a temp fix, up to find time to implement a better design.